# $.noUiSlider vertical slider with max value at top and min value at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, nouislider

$.noUiSlider slider is not working properly while making it vertical and trying to get max value at top and min at bottom using direction option. here is the code below

```
noUiSlider.create(document.getElementById('slider-range'), {
  start: [20, 50],
  direction: 'rtl',
  orientation: 'vertical',
  tooltips: [true,true],
  range: {
    'min': [ 10 ],
    'max': [ 90 ]
  }});
```

[This is the output i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Qpw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try without [ and ] that surrounds your min and max values :

```
   noUiSlider.create(document.getElementById('slider-range'), {
      start: [20, 50],
      direction: 'rtl',
      orientation: 'vertical',
      tooltips: [true,true],
      range: {
        'min': 10,
        'max': 90
      }})
```

Demonstration here : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/BJdYqx

**More details and documentation here :** https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. Still getting the same output.

Comment: @SaktiDebnath Did you define a height ? Here it works : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/BJdYqx

Comment: thanks for the solution, only css was the issue. its working fine.